# Where is the New Order form on the ADMIN side generated in the core files?

Tags: woocommerce

I am having trouble locating where these form elements are being generated, specifically the "State" fields in the Billing and the Shipping sections. Clearly there is some javascript happening. I'm wondering where the HTML and the javascript are being generated in the core files?

I know, I know, don't edit the core files. Don't worry, this is for my own knowledge. I really appreciate any help.

Here is a screenshot of the State dropdown that I am specifically targeting:

[image]

Thanks for any insight you can provide :)

Comment: these seem to be the files that can help you further https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php#L493 
refers to https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/wc-meta-box-functions.php#L189  & https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/admin/meta-boxes-order.js#L19 good luck!

Comment: @L7c1f3r This was super helpful. Thank you!